# I need an easy solution for storing, delivering, and updating product data for a mobile app

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store a companys product data (id, prices, color etc) for about 100 products and retrieve it from both an Android app and an IOS app. The apps will be used in 10 different countries with separate languages and pricing. About 10 000 to 50 000 users/month is expected. This is not an e-commerce or online shopping app but it should display prices to users. No customer data or order data is required for now.

The company employees should be able to update product prices (and perhaps other product info) easily, i.e. some ok interface or by replacing/uploading csv files. The company employees will not be able to add new products after app launch.
Restricted access handling (read or RW permissions) is needed for security.

Could Firebase Cloud Firestore be a good solution for this?
Or is it realistic to have a set of cloud hosted csv files, say one file (~11kb) for each language?

I would prefer to avoid setting up my own database, security, API and managing frontend.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the firestore free tier you will notice that it is 50 000 reads per day. When you say up to 50 000 user per month you probably don't mean that they will be all at the same day on the app and every day. If you write your code clean and efficient you could manage to stay in the free tier.

Regarding the security you could mark some users as admins or use a role based system to ensure that only they can change the data. As I understood all other users are not authenticated but can ready data. For that I would recommend to use [AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). It ensures that only your Apps can access the data.

For the translations if you mean translations for each prouct name you can store the with the product `document` itself to reduce the amount of reads or in a subcollection of the product. Depending on your use case and need.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have started implementing a React CMS for Firestore and it seems to be a good solution so far. Next step is to to add the Firebase Admin SDK to the React project and set up flow for a more granular access restriction with Firebase Auth.

How bad of an idea would it be to structure the data so that each product is in a separate Firestore document? I'm thinking about the ammount of reads from Firestore.

Comment: That would be a normal and recomended approach. For the granulated acces check this project: https://www.react-most-wanted.com/ It has a atomised grants and roles authorisation structure.